# Can't verify openssl public key

Tags: php, ios, openssl, gamekit

I'm trying to use `openssl_verify()` to verify `$payload` with `$publicKey`. 
Here's my code:

```
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($_POST['publicKeyURL']);
$playerID = $_POST['playerID'];
$timestamp = intval($_POST['timestamp']);
$signature = base64_decode($_POST['signature']);
$salt = base64_decode($_POST['salt']);

$payload = $playerID . $bundleID . $timestamp . $salt;

$status = openssl_verify($payload, $signature, $publicKey);
openssl_free_key($publicKey);

if ($status == 1) { /* */ }
```

I'm getting the following error:

> openssl_verify() supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key

The POST information is coming from an iOS app using [this Game Center method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler%3a).

Comment: Are you sure `openssl_pkey_get_public($_POST['publicKeyURL']);` is getting the key? The parameter should be a certificate resource, a local file path, or a PEM formatted key?

Comment: @swiss196 An example value of `$_POST['publicKeyURL']` would be `https://sandbox.gc.apple.com/public-key/gc-sb.cer`

Comment: I don't think you can get a certificate via an URL like that. Try: `openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents($_POST['publicKeyURL']));`. But I'm not 100% sure that'll work either...

Comment: @swiss196 I'm getting the same error :(